# Finding position of missing bits in stream

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

not sure if this is the right channel... Please advise :-)

1. You generate a stream of n bits (1 &  0).

   2. I remove k bits and broadcast the stream of n-k bits.
   3. You start listening to my stream at some point in time (i.e. you probably missed the beginning of the stream).

Task:
Tell me *the original position of the bits that I have removed from your stream*, for the part that you received.

Additional information:

1. Your stream must contain at least 1000 bits, but you can design it any way you like, and you may store it in memory.
2. I will remove no more than 3 consecutive bits.
3. I will remove no more than 10 bits from the original stream.
4. I will broadcast the stream exactly once - no looping etc.

Is this solvable? Maybe with checksums, integrated position encoding...? 
How many bits of my stream do you require to give your answer with absolute certainty?

I found this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2079/determine-missing-number-in-data-stream but there the numbers that may be removed are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intuition is that this is quite doable.

Given an n-bit string (more on that in a bit), there is a relatively efficient decoding algorithm. Set aside the requirement that the adversary not discard more than 3 consecutive bits (it's possible not to, but the algorithm would be more complicated, and I don't think that it's much of a restriction). Initialize a map from each of n+1 positions in the string to a removal count (initially zero) and a head position (initially the key). For each received bit, loop through the map. If the next bit at the head matches the bit, move it forward. Otherwise, increase the removal count. Delete this key from the map if the removal count exceeds 10. Once there is only one unique head position, decoding is finished.

I conjecture that, with high probability, a uniform random string works well. A hand-wavy argument to this effect is that, for every head in an incorrect position, it accrues a removal with probability 1/2. After, say, 200 bits, there should be a small enough probability of survival that over about 1000 heads times about 1000^11/11! choices by the adversary, the probability that an incorrect head survives is negligible. (This argument is hand-wavy because I'm making a bunch of unproven and literally false independence assumptions.)

Comment: Thanks David! One issue I realised now is: suppose you have a sequence with two repeating values (0110) then just one value is removed and (010) Is the broadcast. It's not clear if it is the (1) removed from position 2 or 3... Sigh...

Comment: @Kutscher That's why I was careful to say "unique head position" instead of "unique key".

Comment: I see your point now, wasn't familiar with the terminology. Thank you David!